# Is there a hotkey/shortcut for Print to Web Receipts folder?

Tags: safari

I love the "Save PDF to Web Receipts Folder" in Safari and use it all the time. The only minor annoyance is that it takes a few steps (cmd+P -> click "PDF" -> select "Save PDF to Web Receipts Folder") to use it. Is there a way to setup a hotkey/shortcut for it so that it just takes one quick key combo?

---

[image: Example of the 'Save PDF to Web Receipts Folder' function in Safari]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a very basic Automator Service Applescript with GUI Scripting. Then, use the Keyboard Shortcuts in System Prefs to assign a shortcut.

1. Open Automator and Choose 'Service'
2. Past this script in a 'Run Applescript' Action.

   ```
   tell application "System Events"
       get system attribute "sysv"
       if result is greater than or equal to 4144 then -- Mac OS X 10.3.0
           if UI elements enabled then
               tell application "Safari" to activate
               keystroke "p" using command down
               tell application process "Safari"
                   tell application "System Events"
                       tell process "Safari"
                           click menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
                           delay 1

                           click menu item "Save PDF to Web Receipts Folder" of menu of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
                       end tell
                   end tell
               end tell
           else
               beep
               display dialog "GUI Scripting is not enabled" & return & return & "Open System Preferences and check Enable Access for Assistive Devices in the Accessibility (or Universal Access) preference pane, then run this script again." with icon stop
               if button returned of result is "OK" then
                   tell application "System Preferences"
                       activate
                       set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
                   end tell
               end if
           end if
       else
           beep
           display dialog "This computer cannot run this script" & return & return & "The script uses GUI Scripting technology, which requires an upgrade to Mac OS X 10.3 Panther or newer." with icon caution buttons {"Quit"} default button "Quit"
       end if
   end tell
   ```
3. Set input to 'no input' and Application to 'Safari.app'
4. Save the Automator Service.
5. While still in Automator (or any app) go to the app's 'Services' menu and choose 'Services Preferences'.
6. Scroll rich down until you see your new service.
7. Assign the shortcut, click ok and your done.

Comment: I had some trouble with this the first time I tried. The issue was that I had another global hotkey that was conflicting with the hotkey I was trying to use. Once I changed that it started working as expected. Thanks!